# Spring RestTemplate forward large file to another service

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to forward a large file pulled as an input stream to another service using spring's resttemplate.  I have followed the answer given by @artbristol in this topic: [How to forward large files with RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781885/how-to-forward-large-files-with-resttemplate)

And it looks like it is setting the body of the request properly (grabbing the request with charlesproxy).  The problem is that I have not set the headers correctly since I believe I need to set the content-type as multipart/formdata which I tried by adding this in the callback:

```
request.getHeaders().setContentType(
                new MediaType("multipart", "form-data"));
```

But in the http headers I am still missing the boundary, not sure how to set that and I am sure I am probably missing some other settings.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this out.  Basically I needed to create a Spring message converter that will take in the input stream and write out to the body.  I also basically have to use the Form Message Converter to write out the response body as well.

So in the restTemplate I call an add message converter to add new input stream message converter. In the call back I create a multivaluemap that takes in a string and inputstream and wrap that around an HttpEntity.  Then I create a new instance of the Form Message converter and call write, passing in request, and the mutlivaluemap.

Comment: Your explanation seems pretty clear, but some code sample would go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that I did not include the path to htrace-core.jar in the spark class path:
spark-shell --driver-class-path  /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core.jar:/etc/hbase/conf

Seems like this is new for spark 1.x