# Multipart File Upload Using Spring Rest Template + Spring Web MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am trying to upload a File using RestTemplate with the following code.

```
   MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
   multipartMap.add("file", new ClassPathResource(file));

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setContentType(new MediaType("multipart", "form-data"));

   HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(multipartMap, headers);

   System.out.println("Request for File Upload : " + request);

   ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = template.get().exchange(
                    contextPath.get() + path, HttpMethod.POST, request,
                    byte[].class);
```

I have the `MultipartResolver` bean and Controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public byte[] setImage(@PathVariable("id") Long userId,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    // Upload logic
}
```

And I get the following Exception

```
 org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:255) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:95) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:80) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:67) [log4j-web-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at m.m.m.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(UapAbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:109) [classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_67]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
```

Comment: What's the URL you're accessing that generates the error?

Comment: Doing a POST to http://localhost:8080/myweb/50/image. It is reaching the controller method but file is missing. Don't know why.

Comment: Please share the `multipartResolver` configuration.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19481665/1910582) - something similar

Comment: You declared a request parameter named file, the error message complains about a missing request parameter file and you don't have one in the url you shared. My guess is that is the issue. Also can you try to debug it and see if it enters the `setImage()` function? This will help determine whether the issue is with mapping to the method or inside it.

Comment: You can visit bellow thread. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805956/3073945

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Multipart File Upload worked after following code modification to Upload using RestTemplate

```
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("file", new ClassPathResource(file));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
                    map, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> result = template.get().exchange(
                    contextPath.get() + path, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                    String.class);
```

And adding MultipartFilter to web.xml

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: If the template object is of type RestTemplate, same 400 response I am getting

Comment: I am using the above code in rest client for uploading a file to a rest web service(on another server different from my local machine) but, getting the error as: I/O error on POST request for "http://anothermachine:31112/url/path": class path resource [fileName.csv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: @shazin I also have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181145/httpmessageconverter-for-uploading-a-tar-file-using-resttemplate) in which I am trying to upload tar.gz file but its not working. Can you help me out?

Comment: I'm stumped by the question and this answer.  Neither should compile because `file` is a `MultipartFile` but [`new ClassPathResource()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) requires a `String`.

Comment: `file` is actually a `String` containing the name of the file to be uploaded which is available in the Classpath. Not a `java.io.File`. Obviously the code works for many.

Answer (score 31):

For most use cases, it's not correct to register MultipartFilter in web.xml because Spring MVC already does the work of processing your multipart request.  It's even written in the filter's javadoc.

On the server side, define a multipartResolver bean in your app context:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

On the client side, here's how to prepare the request for use with Spring RestTemplate API:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> pdfHeaderMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    pdfHeaderMap.add("Content-disposition", "form-data; name=filex; filename=" + file.getOriginalFilename());
    pdfHeaderMap.add("Content-type", "application/pdf");
    HttpEntity<byte[]> doc = new HttpEntity<byte[]>(file.getBytes(), pdfHeaderMap);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartReqMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    multipartReqMap.add("filex", doc);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> reqEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multipartReqMap, headers);
    ResponseEntity<MyResponse> resE = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, reqEntity, MyResponse.class);
```

The important thing is really to provide a Content-disposition header using the exact case, and adding name and filename specifiers, otherwise your part will be discarded by the multipart resolver.

Then, your controller method can handle the uploaded file with the following argument:

```
@RequestParam("filex") MultipartFile file
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx a lott man..I was looking for the  client side for days...Thanks very much

Comment: For whatever reason, I needed quotes around the name and filename: `"form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filePart.getSubmittedFileName() + "\"")`

Comment: I was getting error of boundary not set but this post helped me, thanks

Comment: I get an error saying "[org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]" Has anyone faced this?

Comment: Setting the custom multipart resolver solved my problem, thanks!! Just a side note, I had to import the [commons-fileupload](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4) dependency and everything woked fine.

Answer (score 20):

Here are my working example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/files/upload", method =RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    List<String> tempFileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String tempFileName;
    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            tempFileName = "/tmp/" + file.getOriginalFilename();
            tempFileNames.add(tempFileName);
            fo = new FileOutputStream(tempFileName);
            fo.write(file.getBytes());
            fo.close();
            map.add("files", new FileSystemResource(tempFileName));
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(uploadFilesUrl, requestEntity, String.class);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String fileName : tempFileNames) {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        f.delete();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing the files locally, you can pass the MultipartFiles through by using `file.getResource()` instead of `new FileSystemResource(tempFileName)`. The for loop would look like this: `for (MultipartFile file : files) {map.add("files", file.getResource); }`

Answer (score 13):

A correct file upload would like this:

HTTP header:

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ

Http body:

> --ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="my.txt"
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> Content-Length: ...
>
> <...file data in base 64...>
>
> --ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ--

and code is like this:

```
public void uploadFile(File file) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String url = "http://localhost:8080/file/user/upload";
            HttpMethod requestMethod = HttpMethod.POST;

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);


            MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
                    .builder("form-data")
                    .name("file")
                    .filename(file.getName())
                    .build();

            fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
            HttpEntity<byte[]> fileEntity = new HttpEntity<>(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), fileMap);

            MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            body.add("file", fileEntity);

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, requestMethod, requestEntity, String.class);

            System.out.println("file upload status code: " + response.getStatusCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Comment: Best (most complete) answer I've found, thanks!

Comment: How could an additional (POJO) be sent with the fields sent as request parameters?

Comment: This solution worked for me without using any additional libraries. Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: The unabridged version of this answer can be found here: https://medium.com/red6-es/uploading-a-file-with-a-filename-with-spring-resttemplate-8ec5e7dc52ca

Answer (score 12):

For those who are getting the error as:

```
I/O error on POST request for "anothermachine:31112/url/path";: class path 
resource [fileName.csv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist.
```

It can be resolved by using the

```
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
```

If the file is not present in the classpath, and an absolute path is required.

Comment: My issue was a bit different: `ClassPathResource` was used for a file that was not accessible in classpath, and changing it to `FileSystemResource` made my day. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

More based on the feeling, but this is the error you would get if you missed to declare a bean in the context configuration, so try adding

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```