# MultipartFile is null when I use CommonsMultipartResolver in my Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-boot

I would like to implement upload handler method in my Spring Boot app. I want to use `CommonsMultipartResolver` instead of `StandardServletMultipartResolver`. I have the the following problem:

My controller method parameter (file) is always set to null. I saw in java docs of `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`: 
*This filter needs to run after multipart processing in case of a multipart POST request, due to its inherent need for checking a POST body parameter.*

I tried to set order for the multipartFilter bean but it did not help. When I debug, I see that `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` is always called before `MultipartFilter`.  I am using Spring Boot version 1.3.0.RELEASE and Java based config. How can I set the order that   `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` comes after `MultipartFilter`?

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();        
    resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(52428800); 
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
        MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public FileTransport create(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
        MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    //return fileService.create(userId, file);
    return new FileTransport();
}
```

If I modify the method to include Request param like below:

@RequestParam(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file

It throws an exception: 'Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present'.

If I use `StandardServletMultipartResolver`, everything works as expected.

Comment: As already [discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2958#issuecomment-227536841) the order of your `MultipartFilter` is wrong. It needs to be less than the order of `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` which is -10000. If that doesn't help, can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson the order of HiddenHttpMethodFilter is not -10000, but HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+10. But even if u set the MultipartFilter ahead of it, uploading fails, this time with a `java.io.IOException: Missing content for multipart request
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractMultipartParameters(Request.java:390)`. Is CommonsMultipartResolver at all compatible with Spring Boot?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson spring-boot version is 1.2.8.

Comment: @kpentchev You are using a different version of Spring Boot so things may well not be the same. Comments aren't the right place to solve your problem; ask a new question if this one doesn't help.

Answer (score 7):

In Spring Boot to use CommonsMultipartResolver you need to disable MultipartAutoConfiguration by adding following annotation to your configuration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
```

My multipart resolver bean:

```
 @Bean
 public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
     CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
     multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5 * 1024 * 1024);
     return multipartResolver;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think they have the resolved the issue in Spring-Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE version:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipart = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipart.setMaxUploadSize(3 * 1024 * 1024);
    return multipart;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

You also need to exclude Spring-Boot's `MultipartAutoConfiguration.class`

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/12-developer-labors/spring-boot-file-upload-via-rest-controller-6dcc7e5d6e54) it is important to properly craft one's multipart request when using the CommonsMultipartResolver which in turns relies on commons-fileupload. 
I'll follow the recommendation made in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005690/1722236). Note how we set the multipart request content-type and content-disposition.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> fileHeaders = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    fileHeaders.add("Content-type", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
    fileHeaders.add("Content-disposition", "form-data; name=file; filename=originalFileName.txt");
    File myFile = new File(...);
    HttpEntity multipartFile = new HttpEntity<>(myFile.getBytes(), fileHeaders);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    form.add("file", multipartFile);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/file/", new HttpEntity<>(form, headers), String.class);
    System.err.println(response.toString());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the below code worked for me :

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {

  final CommonsMultipartResolver cmr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  long maxSize = parseSize(multipartConfig.getMaxFileSize());
  cmr.setMaxUploadSize(maxSize);
  cmr.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
  cmr.getFileUpload().setProgressListener(
      (long pBytesRead, long pContentLength, int pItems) -> {
        LOG.info(" Uploaded {}% ", pBytesRead*100/pContentLength);
      });

  return cmr;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing problems with *PUT* requests, you need to extend **CommonsMultipartResolver** and override the **isMultipart** method. Then use this new class as the **MultipartResolver** bean.

```
public class CustomCommonsMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String contentType = new ServletRequestContext(request).getContentType();
        if (contentType == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (contentType.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith("multipart/")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```