# Spring rest controller's " MultipartFile[] multipartFiles" always recieves [ ] or null files

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, multipart, spring-restcontroller

I am using Spring 4 with Java Config. I want multiple files to be uploaded to the server but problem is my MultipartFile[ ] parameter will always receive empty/[ ] parameter. Let me share my code here is my 'AppConfig'

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

So i registered my multipartResolver after that i wrote this controller which is doing nothing but receiving files.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<PutObjectResult> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {

    System.out.println("Multipart file length is  "+multipartFiles.length);
    return s3Wrapper.upload(multipartFiles);
}
```

Here my MultipartFile[] multipartFiles is always empty/[ ] no matter how much images/files i send from my client. I am using 'PostMan' to send my files here is screen shot attached of sending request to multipart controller from 'postMan'
[image: PostMan Send Request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem just by putting a form in jsp and test my method with form submit. Also i used HttpClient, for sending request and it worked. I am not able to understand why but somehow the issue is with 'PostMan' tool through which i was hitting my restcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter`?

If not see this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964688/multipart-file-upload-using-spring-rest-template-spring-web-mvc/27097798#27097798)

Comment: No it is automatically get configured with "public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver()" method. As this is java config so we do't need xml. Beside that i have found the solution i am updating my answer, please if you find this question use full upvote it so that in future other persons can also get help. Thanks