# 400 Bad Request with spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have spring rest service such this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
        path = "/getdata", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, produces =     MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public
@ResponseBody
Result getBarcode(@RequestParam("text") String sl,
                  @RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file)  {
                ... some logic
     return new Result(text, message, !processingError);
 }
```

When i call this from **http** form it works fine and return **json text**. But when i trying to call this from java code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("text", "123");
    map.add("imageFile", new File("...path to file..."));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
      headers.setAccept(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml"));
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new  HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
    ResponseEntity<BcResult> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/getdata", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, BcResult.class);
```

Then i am getting **400 Bad request error**. Can`t figure out what is wrong with this code...

Comment: remove consume multipart/form-data

Comment: It does not help. Getting the same error

Comment: Have you check this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27097798/4418951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your file like this.

```
 map.add("imageFile", new FileSystemResource(new File("...path to file...")));
```

or like this

```
map.add("imageFile", new ClassPathResource("...path to file..."));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It WORKS!! :)