# how to upload file from server(Spring framework) to other server (example:112.12.15.2)

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm newbiew in Spring and Android. And now I'm developing an app android to send image to my server (localhost:192.168.1.5:8080) and from my server I have to send image to other server (example: 112.15.21.32). I wrote Spring API for sending from app android to my server (localhost) and it's ok. But now I don't know how to code for sending image from my server to other server(112.15.21.32). Who can help me or give me some advices? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this solution on stackoverflow (already asked) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263348/file-upload-communication-between-two-spring-boot-application, Let me know if works

Comment: NP man! am so happy that I helped someone :)