# MultipartFile + String as Request Param using RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

In my spring boot Application, I need to pass String value along with MultipartFile as `Requestparam`.
**Controller** is below where I'm converting **MultipartFile** to `java.io.File` and then passing it to DAO controller with help of `restTemplate`.

Request from Angular will hit Upload Controller first then **UploadController** is client(Java) and it will be calling server **svs-ba-dao Controller** with Base URL.
`csvUpload` contains base URL: http://localhost:8082/svs-ba-dao/csvUpload?parentPkId=&file=multipartFile

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UploadController {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(UploadController.class);

    @Value("${salama.dao.csvUpload.rest.url}")
    private String csvUpload;
    
    @Autowired
    UploadHelperService uploadHelperService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/csvUpload")
    public String csvUpload(@QueryParam("parentPkId") String parentPkId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
        
        log.info("Calling csvUpload :" + csvUpload);
        final HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        File cnvFile = uploadHelperService.multipartToFile(file,file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("Converted File Name is -->"+cnvFile.getName());
        final MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        
        data.add("parentPkId", parentPkId);
        data.add("file", new FileSystemResource(cnvFile));
        
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(data, requestHeaders);
    
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        ResponseEntity<String> obj =restTemplate.exchange(csvUpload, HttpMethod.POST,
            requestEntity, String.class);
        
        return obj.getBody();
}
    
    
}
```

> In svs-ba-dao Controller catching it as below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/csvUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String csvUpload(@RequestParam String parentPkId, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        log.info("Entered method csvUpload() of svs-ba-dao.class");
        return uploadService.csvUpload(parentPkId,file);
    }
```

I have included these properties into the application.properties file of my application:
`spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=1MB spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=1MB`

So I start my application and call the `/csvUpload` that generate the POST request.
**i'm getting below error.**

```
Converted File Name is -->testInput_TxnMpMotSlv.csv
2019-01-24T15:12:41,217 ERROR [[localhost].[/svs-ba-dao].[dispatcherServlet]] [http-nio-8085-exec-2] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/svs-ba-dao] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.svs-ba-dao.controller.UploadController.csvUpload(UploadController.java:59) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
```

> Error is in resttemplate as it is taking null, but syntactically way of calling RestTemplate is correct as i'm not getting any  error.
> am I calling **Base URL**properly?by passing `requestparam` values. i.e
> parentPkId=?&file=multipartFile

http://localhost:8082/svs-ba-dao/csvUpload?parentPkId=&file=multipartFile
honestly i haven't worked on this before.
Where i'm doing wrong, any leads or corrections welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: surround your RestTemplate call with try catch and sysout the obj.getBody() , see what exeption raised !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found where I was wrong

> csvUpload will hold the URL which should be passed in rest template

```
 @Value("${salama.dao.csvUpload.rest.url}")
        private String csvUpload;
```

I found that base URL: i.e csvUpload
`http://localhost:8082/svs-ba-dao/csvUpload?parentPkId=&file=multipartFile` 
sending from **UploadController** was wrong.

No need to specify anything like `multipartFile` for `mediaType` in URL. it will automatically pick up.
but for some of the URL's need to specify `?mediaType=json` if sending JSON object.

Here is my updated base **URL** :`http://localhost:8082/svs-ba-dao/csvUpload?parentPkId=&file=`

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in calling. Look at your stack trace error carefully.
In csvUpload method you print this:

```
System.out.println("Converted File Name is -->"+cnvFile.getName());
```

this line printed in log:

```
Converted File Name is -->testInput_TxnMpMotSlv.csv
```

So calling was ok. problem in here:

```
at com.svs-ba-dao.controller.UploadController.csvUpload(UploadController.java:59)
```

Just check at line number **59** in **csvUpload** method of **UploadController**. you will find your error.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964688/multipart-file-upload-using-spring-rest-template-spring-web-mvc). how to call multipart using *rest template.*

Comment: `ResponseEntity<String> obj =restTemplate.exchange(csvUpload, HttpMethod.POST,
            requestEntity, String.class);` this is the line i'm getting error. but couldn't dig in what is root cause as syntactically its correct @sajib

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things to understand what is actually happening:

1. Try calling your endpoint for csvUpload in `svs-ba-dao Controller` from postman to see if it is working independently. Also, update your csvUpload method to

   `@RequestMapping(value="/csvUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public String csvUpload(@RequestParam("parentPkId") String parentPkId, 
          @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
       log.info("Entered method csvUpload() of svs-ba-dao.class");
       return uploadService.csvUpload(parentPkId,file);
   }`
2. Surround your RestTemplate call to `try-catch`

   `ResponseEntity<String> obj =restTemplate.exchange(csvUpload, HttpMethod.POST,
           requestEntity, String.class);`

in order to see an exception which is coming from `svs-ba-dao Controller`.

Comment: I tried calling `svs-ba-dao Controller` which works fine independently. but problem is  when i tried to call it from ** `UploadController`**.

Comment: can you check by adding `headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data"` in `svs-ba-dao Controller`?