# Spring resttemplate - Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: spring, resttemplate

Try sent photo as byte array through resttemplate and receive "Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server".
All errors
`org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://servername12:8091/rs/photo": Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server`

However, if I sent this array without end byte it send successful.
My code:

````
    @ResponseBody
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
    {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
                headers.setContentLength(1000000000);
                HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>(bytes, headers);
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

                ResponseEntity<ValidatorResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(VALIDATOR_URL + "photo", bytes, ValidatorResponse.class);
                System.out.println(response.getBody().getCode());

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one simple request in Google and all first links show the proper way:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27097798/4573580
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload

Use `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` and `ResponseEntity<String>`

Comment: I changed Content-Type to MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and ResponseEntity to ResponseEntity<String>, as you wrote. However, I also receive this error as before (org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://servername12:8091/rs/photo": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset)