# Spring RestTemplate POST multipart/form-data which has special characters in filename

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a method which calls an external service using Spring's RestTemplate:

```
  public SomeClass methodThatCallsAnExternalService(String id, String fileName, byte[] file) throws IOException {
    Resource resourceFile = new FileSystemResource(file, fileName);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8");

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("id", id);
    body.add("inputFile", resourceFile);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    return objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), SomeClass.class);
  }
```

and the `FileSystemResource` is defined as follows:

```
  private static class FileSystemResource extends ByteArrayResource {

  private String fileName;

  public FileSystemResource(byte[] byteArray, String filename) {
    super(byteArray);
    this.fileName = filename;
  }

  public String getFilename() {
    return fileName;
  }

  public void setFilename(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
  }
}
```

This works as it should in most cases, but if the `fileName` argument contains special characters such as õäöü, the RestTemplate request fails and the only response given is

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Execution exception</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGXR... (7772 bytes)]]
```

How can I make the RestTemplate accept special characters? As can be seen, I have already tried specifying charset in a header and adding a new message converter, but neither worked.

Comment: The problem can be in the server side.

Comment: Do you mean the external service where the call is made? If you do then no, because the external service is used for the same purpose in other applications, all of which handle the special characters correctly.

Comment: You could try a slightly different approach as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650486/3080094

Comment: Cannot use that approach because the external service does not accept requests in that format and I have no ability to do necessary modifications so it would accept.