# Streaming upload via @Bean-provided RestTemplateBuilder buffers full file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, streaming, reverse-proxy, resttemplate

I'm building a reverse-proxy for uploading large files (multiple gigabytes), and therefore want to use a streaming model that does not buffer entire files.  Large buffers would introduce latency and, more importantly, they could result in out-of-memory errors.

My client class contains

```
@Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {

    int REST_TEMPLATE_MODE = 1; // 1=streams, 2=streams, 3=buffers

    return 
        REST_TEMPLATE_MODE == 1 ? new RestTemplate() :
        REST_TEMPLATE_MODE == 2 ? (new RestTemplateBuilder()).build() :
        REST_TEMPLATE_MODE == 3 ? restTemplateBuilder.build() : null;
}
```

and

```
public void upload_via_streaming(InputStream inputStream, String originalname) {

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream) {
        @Override public String getFilename() { return originalname; }
        @Override public long contentLength() { return -1; }
    };

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    body.add("myfile", inputStreamResource);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body,headers);

    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(UPLOAD_URL, requestEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println("response: "+response);
}
```

This is working, but notice my `REST_TEMPLATE_MODE` value controls whether or not it meets my streaming requirement.

**Question**: Why does `REST_TEMPLATE_MODE == 3` result in full-file buffering?

---

References:

- [How to forward large files with RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36226006/86967)
- [How to send Multipart form data with restTemplate Spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461661/86967)
- [Spring - How to stream large multipart file uploads to database without storing on local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38200145/86967) -- establishing the InputStream
- [How to autowire RestTemplate using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339656/86967)
- [Design notes and usage caveats, also: `restTemplate` does *not* support streaming *downloads*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48041200/86967)

Comment: BTW: Full-file buffering was detected by observing the symptoms: latency and server memory profile.

Comment: Related?: [Shouldn't RestTemplate be instantiated per @Service class ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957550/86967)

Comment: Interesting description about "the most suitable `ClientHttpRequestFactory`": [Class RestTemplateBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html)

Comment: I find it amusing that `setBufferRequestBody(false)` doesn't guarantee that result.

Comment: Possibly useful: [Spring RestTemplate (setBufferRequestBody as false) does not like MultiValueMap request body, which contains an InputStream object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40577107/86967)

Comment: Another input stream: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782026/springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload

Comment: More on input-side streaming: [Cannot get Spring Boot to lazily resolve a multipart file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49234757/86967)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, the instance of `RestTemplateBuilder` provided as an `@Bean` by Spring Boot includes an interceptor (filter) associated with actuator/metrics -- and the interceptor interface requires buffering of the request body into a simple `byte[]`.

If you instantiate your own `RestTemplateBuilder` or `RestTemplate` from scratch, it won't include this by default.

---

I seem to be the only person visiting this post, but just in case it helps someone before I get around to posting a complete solution, I've found a big clue:

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().forEach(item->System.out.println(item));
```

displays...

```
org.SF.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor
```

If I clear the interceptor list via `setInterceptors`, it solves the problem. Furthermore, I found that any interceptor, even if it only performs a NOP, will introduce full-file buffering.

---

### public class SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory { ...

I have explicitly set `bufferRequestBody = false`, but apparently this code is bypassed if interceptors are used.  This would have been nice to know earlier...

```
@Override
public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = openConnection(uri.toURL(), this.proxy);
    prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod.name());

    if (this.bufferRequestBody) {
        return new SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest(connection, this.outputStreaming);
    }
    else {
        return new SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest(connection, this.chunkSize, this.outputStreaming);
    }
}
```

### public abstract class InterceptingHttpAccessor extends HttpAccessor { ...

This shows that the `InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory` is used if the list of `interceptors` is not empty.

```
/**
 * Overridden to expose an {@link InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory}
 * if necessary.
 * @see #getInterceptors()
 */
@Override
public ClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory() {
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = getInterceptors();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
        ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = this.interceptingRequestFactory;
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(super.getRequestFactory(), interceptors);
            this.interceptingRequestFactory = factory;
        }
        return factory;
    }
    else {
        return super.getRequestFactory();
    }
}
```

### class InterceptingClientHttpRequest extends AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest { ...

The interfaces make it clear that using `InterceptingClientHttpRequest` requires buffering `body` to a `byte[]`.  There is not an option to use a streaming interface.

```
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse execute(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
```