# How to proxy internal mjpeg endpoint via RestController

Tags: java, spring, mjpeg

I need to expose a local Motion JPEG endpoint (ex. "http://192.168.1.10/video.mjpg") passing from an endpoint in a RestController of my Application Server (jhipster gateway), because I need to gurantee grants and authorization to stream it.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856005/spring-resttemplate-streaming-response-into-another-request) solution

```java
@GetMapping("/video")
@Timed
public void stream(@RequestParam(name = "url") String url, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        log.debug("REST request to stream : {}", url);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/x-mixed-replace");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.execute(
            url,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            (ClientHttpRequest requestCallback) -> {},
            responseExtractor -> {
                IOUtils.copy(responseExtractor.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
                return null;
            });
    }
```

But it didn't work.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the following code to work using the webflux api.

`bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)` converts the response body into a reactive Flux of DataBuffer objects. And within `doOnNext`, it reads the data from each DataBuffer and writes it to the response's output stream.

Important to note that `DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);` must be called or it will result in memory leak.

```
private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
  .baseUrl("baseUrl")
  // .filters(...) // perhaps authentication filters
  .build();

@GetMapping
public void stream(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
  response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=myboundary");

  try {
    webClient.get()
    .uri("/the-uri.mjpg")
    .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=myboundary"))
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, clientResponse ->
      clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class).map(RuntimeException::new))
    .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
    .doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
      try (final var input = dataBuffer.asInputStream()) {
        input.transferTo(response.getOutputStream());
        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    })
    .blockLast();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // the client has probably disconnected
  }
}
```